# Проблема с сохранением файлов на xiaomi redmi 3

Tags: java, android, io

Всем привет!

У меня есть код, который сохраняет текстовый файл. Но я не указываю куда именно его нужно сохранить, он куда-то сохраняется по умолчанию. Я решил узнать, куда же сохраняет все эти файлы и вписал такой код после того как файл сохраняется:

```
Log.d(TAG, newfile.getAbsolutePath());
```

В логах пишет такой путь: `/data/data/com.example.admin.notepadv1/files`

Но проблема в том, что папки com.example.admin.notepadv1 - не существует. В папке `data/data` есть только одна папка с названием `com.elex.im.cok.app` , в нем папка config, а в нем файл user_session 
Ничего близкого к моему сохраненному файлу я не нашел.

Вопросы:

1. Как найти папку куда сохраняются файлы? На самсунге эта программа работает нормально, файл создается, а вот на `xiaomi redmi` - нет
2. Как мне указать папку, куда нужно сохранять файл?

Comment: насколько мне известно содержимое папки `data/data` можно просматривать только под рутом

Comment: Указывайте сами путь, куда сохранять файл. Зачем сохранять куда-то, а потом гадать?

Comment: как указать путь сохранения для файла?

Comment: Руководство читали: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) ?

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, Вы сохраняете файлы в [Internal Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

Исходя из документации, файлы, сохраненные в Internal Storage, видны только приложению, которое их сохранило и не видны сторонним программам и пользователю. Это некая песочница приложения. Однако получить доступ к этим файлам можно, имея рут-права.

*Могу путать*, но на каких-то версиях системы или у каких-то вендоров достучаться до этой области памяти таки можно было даже без рута.

> Как мне указать папку, куда нужно сохранять файл?

При создании объекта `newfile` явно укажите путь к директории (первый параметр):

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "FileName.txt");
```

или

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "FileName.txt");
```

В первом случае, файл расположен в Internal Storage, во втором – в External Storage, которую Вы можете свободно просматривать.

**UPD**. Из комментариев:

> Стоит добавить, что для второго случая необходимо получить пермишн `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Да, разумеется, получить пермишн необходимо. Также необходимо проверить стейт External Storage и еще много всяких вещей. Но цель этого ответа – в общих чертах, а не энциклопедически, обрисовать тему, поэтому для более глубокого изучения работы с файлами в Android – необходимо почитать соответствующие доки или литературу.

Comment: Стоит добавить, что для второго случая необходимо получить пермишн `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Буду пробовать